# Trying to change Android API 28 to 23

Tags: java, android

Could someone help we with this piece of code?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pl.mac.maciej.bakustheclicker"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

I tried everything but every time while I'm trying to make it working on Android 6.0, it returns error and it doesn't work. Could someone tell me how to convert app from API 28/25 to API 23? It's not a big project, just a simple clicker.
Thanks for every answer :)

Comment: Why? You can run an app that targets API 28 on API 23. Just keep `minSdkVersion` at 23.

Comment: OK, but it says that Google Play requires that apps target API level 26 or higher.

Comment: Yes, target. `targetSdkVersion` is NOT `minSdkVersion`. Set `targetSdkVersion` to 28 and build.

Comment: the same thing.

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pl.mac.maciej.bakustheclicker"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }`

Comment: And did you sync the project?

Comment: App stops working.

Comment: Sync? You mean build? I'm begineer :(

Comment: Sync Project with Gradle Files?

Comment: If yes, I did. Nothing change

Comment: App stops working is not helpful. When you raise `targetSdkVersion` to 28, You acknowledge your app was tested on and complies with behavior and api changes up to Android Pie. If you're having exception thrown when building or when running the app You have to post the error stack trace or we won't be able to help.

Comment: Paweł, I don't know what to save. I`m not getting any error messages. Only that app stops working. Code works on Android 7 and 9 phones. Debugging, I'm getting this:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SEUw1ieP

Comment: I want to make this app working on Android 6 and 7

Comment: Change the targetsdk version to 23 ,if its not work please share your error log cat .

Comment: try to set compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion the same value

Comment: So, Here is the full debug log https://pastebin.com/UcqfbvGZ . It says that it can't inflat class ImageView in maint activity. Line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Sorry, this line super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Sorry, finally it returns error

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); Names etc. are called correctly. I'm trying to use API 23